# How to mount two partition for different purposes?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

[This image shows that the 500GB sda1 is not mounted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFRDV.png)I have an 1TB hard drive disk & I want to mount 400GB for system files (as like the files of installed softwares & games) , & the remaining storage for my personal storage where I'll store my photos, videos or documents. How can I do this on Ubuntu 20.04LTS ?
I'm already using an 250GB NVME SSD as my boot drive which was partitioned automatically when I installed the OS. I've partitioned my HDD into two parts but how can I auto-mount them for two different purposes?

Comment: Linux is not like Windows. You can't choose where software gets installed, with notable exceptions (like games from Steam). In general partitions are a poor tool for organization, that's what folders are for.  Your partitions will be mounted as folders in Ubuntu anyway.  It's not clear what is the problem you are experiencing. Your volumes with readable file systems should already be mounted?  Are they not? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: The SSD volume was mounted but the Hdd I bought earlier is not mounted & I need to mount this HDD manually & I don't know how to mount it for the whole system. It was an uncollected storage but I partioned it via Gparted & then I think the partitions are needed to be mounted manually... How can I mount the partitions of the HDD for software installation?

Comment: Sir I've edited the post & added a screenshot from the terminal. & I also understood the concept you wanted to portray about the "partitions & folders"  and I'm thinking about mounting my full HDD in the / directory. will it be safe to do that as my ssd is already mounted on that directory?

Comment: You can mount your 500GB drive wherever you like. For example you could create a directory called “data” at /data or /home/username/data. (Change username to whatever your user name is). You don’t need to mount it manually every time you boot. Instead you add an entry to the /etc/fstab file. It’s not difficult to do this but it can mess up the boot process if you change the entry for the ssd when you do it. Search on here for answers to questions about fstab before diving in.

Comment: One way to create & use data partition(s). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk